# How to Mapping with Automapper dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, automapper

im trying to use the AutoMapper dynamically
i have more than 20 TypeClasses that i receive from another library Project and it can be added more in a future (i dont control that)

Im using
Automapper 8.1
.Net 3.1
C# 8

in this case i have a DTO called TypeTableUpsert

```
public class TypeTableUpsert
    {

        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public long TypeID { get; set; }
        public string TypeCode { get; set; }
        public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and the tables which comes from the library call like ProductType, FileType

```
public class ProductType 
    {
        public long ProductTypeID {get;set}
        public string ProductTypeCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }
        public string ProductTypeDescription { get; set; }
 }
```

```
public class FileType 
    {
        public long FileTypeID {get;set}
        public string FileTypeCode { get; set; }
        public string FileTypeName { get; set; }
        public string FileTypeDescription { get; set; }
 }
```

im trying to create a Dynamic Map with Automapper

in the example below is the normal way to map a ProductType but im trying to avoid to create a lot of Mappings

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cgg => cgg.CreateMap<TypeTableUpsertModel, ProductType>().ForMember(dest =>dest.ProductTypeDescription,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TypeDescription)));
```

im trying do something like that but im getting an errors

```
// im getting the Type Correctly
Type myType = Assamblies.ExportedTypes.SingleOrDefault(types => types.Name == typeModel.TypeTableName);

// here is were im getting the error using MyType
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cgg => cgg.CreateMap<TypeTableUpsertModel, myType>()
.ForMember(dest=> dest.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p=>p.Name.Contains("TypeDescription")).FirstOrDefault(), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TypeDescription));
```

//i Got the next Error

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
  Source=AutoMapper
  StackTrace:
   at AutoMapper.Internal.ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(LambdaExpression lambdaExpression)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpression`2.ForMember[TMember](Expression`1 destinationMember, Action`1 memberOptions)
   at StewartConnect.Admin.Profiles.TypeTableProfile..ctor() in D:\Repos\StewartRepos\StewartConnect.Admin.APIs\StewartConnect.Admin\Profiles\TypeTableProfile.cs:line 43
```

im already tried in different ways but i cant make it work

Comment: You could take a leaf out of the EAI data transformation community and use XSLT instead of AutoMapper.  Not only does XSLT support dynamic transformation but XSLT files are considered _deployable artifacts_ and so can be updated and deployed **without requiring your app to be recompiled**.

Comment: Does the EntityBase class have public or protected complex types  ? in this case you need to check this special API "IncludeMembers" :
https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: The entitybase doesnt really matter i just forget delete for this example, im just tried in with the base Classes

Comment: Foreach type in types, CreateMap.

Comment: I am also working on something similar where I have a child class list which has reference to parent class object and Automapper creates issue with this. I need to ignore the parent class object property in child class. But I don't know how to do it. Solution to above question might help me. Please shed some light if anyone know how to do this.

Comment: i Dont Want to Create a Maps for every Types because it comes from DataBase and can grow or Shring i want to do Dinamically